# Xamarin Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i have a master detail page, on my menu when i click on it to navigate to other page, i got this error:

**System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Android.Renderscripts.RenderScript'.'**

**BUT**, it only happen when i'm calling this code:

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await LoadContent();
    }
```

If i don't call the LoadContent function, the menu works fine and i'm able to navigate to other pages.

My LoadContent code:

```
    public async Task<firstContentJson> LoadContent()
    {
        string connectionUrl = "https://myurl.com/app/getcontent.php";
        object userInfos = new { };
        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInfos);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonObj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(connectionUrl),
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                Content = content
            };
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            string dataResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            firstContentJson result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<firstContentJson>(dataResult);
            try
            {

                string contentid = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["content_id"].ToString();
                string rep = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["rep"].ToString();
                string creator = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["creator"].ToString();
                string text = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["text"].ToString();
                string img = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["img"].ToString();
                string totalrate = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["totalrate"].ToString();
                //string vid = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["vid"].ToString();
                string date = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["date"].ToString();
                string name = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["name"].ToString();
                string pic = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["pic"].ToString();
                string visits = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["visits"].ToString();
                string lvl = JObject.Parse(dataResult)["lvl"].ToString();
                

                //inicio load first content
                imgTop.Source = "https://myurl.com/" + img;
                avUser.Source = "https://myurl.com/" + pic;
                txtName.Text = "@"+name;
                txtDesc.Text = text;
                imgContent.Source = "https://myurl.com/" + img;
                txtRate.Text = rep;
                if(Convert.ToInt32(totalrate)>0)
                {
                    txtInfos.Text = "Avaliado por " + totalrate + " pessoas";
                }
                else
                {
                    txtInfos.Text = "Seja o primeiro a avaliar esse conteúdo!";
                }
                indload.IsVisible = false;
                indload.IsRunning = false;
            }
            catch
            {
                indload.IsVisible = false;
                indload.IsRunning = false;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Someone can help me, please?

**EDIT:**  [Picture of the error when i click on the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPHyp.jpg)

Comment: Try to debug your code and see where the object is disposed.

Comment: i just added a picture of what i got when i click on the menu. It happens when i'm running the app, i can compile the app without errors

Comment: could it be because you are trying to access some properties that are defined inside the (using Http ...) block? I'd try to move the code after response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;out of the using block or for the sake of test dont dispose HttpClient e.g. dont use using block and just do httpClient = new HttpClient()

Comment: hi @ihorbond , i tried. I removed "using http..." and just kept what you said, but i still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: the problem was a plugin called Sharpnado.Shadows.
I removed it from my Master page and everything is working fine again.